# How can I get the MaskMoney jQuery plugin to wait until I enter a value, and allow me to delete an entered value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I wrote some jQuery to update inputted vals to "currency" type, so that entering "1" would change to "1.00" on exit (blur), entering "2.5" would change to "2.50" etc.like so:

```
$(document).on("blur", '[id$=boxAmount1]', function (e) {        $('[id$=boxAmount1]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount1]').val()).toFixed(2));
});

$(document).on("blur", '[id$=boxAmount2]', function (e) {        $('[id$=boxAmount2]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount2]').val()).toFixed(2));
});
```

(etc.)

The MaskMoney plugin is supposed to do all this with:

```
$('[id*=boxAmount]').maskMoney();
```

The problem is that this has the Clippy-like behavior of jumping to my "assistance" too quickly, and blocking attempts to undo its overeager guesses. What I mean is, on entering a "boxamount" input text element, "0.00" is added. If I want to enter some value, it adds that somewhere within the "0.00", resulting in a Frankensteining of the value; if I try to backspace over the value to remove it so as to "start from scratch," it disallows that. It becomes sort of a Pandora's Textbox - once a value has been generated for it, it won't go away.

Is there a way to tame this potentially useful beast?